# Nodemailer (Error: queryA EREFUSED)

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, gmail

Уже 3-ий день пытаюсь пофиксить одну проблему. Использую nodemailer, чтоб отправить сообщение на почту, но выдаёт всё время одну и ту же ошибку. Всё в gmail настроено. Прикол ещё в том, что пару недель назад я делал то же самое и всё работало.
Вот ошибка:

```
Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.gmail.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:210:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'EDNS',
  syscall: 'queryA',
  hostname: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Вот код:

```
  this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
      port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
      },
    })
```

Сами данные из .env:

```
SMTP_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT=587
SMTP_USER=mygmail@gmail.com
SMTP_PASSWORD=mypass
```

Comment: 1. Попробуйте другой порт для гугла
2. Убедитесь что в самом gmail вы включили доступ для сторонних приложений
3. И помойму google использует SSL хотя у вас написано secure: false(если это поле отвечает за что-то другое извините не знал(не работал ранее с этим модулем"

Comment: я уже и 465 порт использовал, и secure: true ставил, и комбинировал всё это. Ничего не помогло. Доступ сторонних приложений включен

Comment: С другого IP адреса/провайдера пробовали?

Comment: да, там работает